# automapping nested components naming conventions

Tags: fluent-nhibernate

Im making the switch from Fluent Mapping to Automapping in my current project.

If I have the following domain:

```
public class Matter{
  public Client Client{get;set;}
}

public class Client {
    public Name Name{get;set;}
}

public class Name{
    public string FirstName{get;set;}
    public string LastName{get;set;}
}
```

When Automapping this model, the column names for the Name component are expected to be:

```
Name_FirstName
Name_LastName
```

(i already have an underscore convention).

Is there a convention I could implement that would get the automapper to generate column names like:

```
Client_Name_FirstName
Client_Name_LastName
```

I hope ive described that effectively.

Cheers,
Byron

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to pick up an old message but for the sake of others coming from a search engine perhaps http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Conventions is what you're after?